# Custom Visualizer for DbCommand

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, debuggervisualizer

Hi im trying to create a custom Visualizer for the DbCommand object that should be used in Visual studio 2013.

i have the following code

```
using VisualizerTest;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(TestVisualizer), typeof(CommandObjectSource), Target = typeof(DbCommand), Description = "Test")]

namespace VisualizerTest
{
    public class TestVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            DbCommand command;
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = objectProvider.GetData())
                {
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    command = (DbCommand)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
                MessageBox.Show(command.CommandText);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace VisualizerTest
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CommandObjectSource : VisualizerObjectSource
    {
        public override void GetData(object target, Stream outgoingData)
        {
            if (target != null && target is DbCommand)
            {
                DbCommand command = (DbCommand)target;

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                formatter.Serialize(outgoingData, command);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the `CommandObjectSource` is never invoked and instead i get a exception

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.RemoteObjectSourceException: Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
```

My understanding was that by using a custom VisualizerObjectSource i would get around the Serialization issue?

As a side note i have tried to change `Target = typeof(DbCommand)` to `Target = typeof(SqlCommand)` and it made no difference.

Test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Field1 FROM table WHERE Field2 = @Value1"))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", 1338);
            TestValue(command);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void TestValue(object value)
    {
        VisualizerDevelopmentHost visualizerHost = new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(value, typeof(TestVisualizer));
        visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are explicitly creating the `VisualizerDevelopmentHost` it won't use the `DebuggerVisualizerAttribute` so you have to pass in your `CommandObjectSource` as the third parameter:

```
VisualizerDevelopmentHost visualizerHost = 
    new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(value, typeof(TestVisualizer),                  
                                         typeof(CommandObjectSource));
```

With this change your `CommandObjectSource` will be called but you still have the serialization problem because the `BinaryFormatter` also needs the class to be marked as `Seralizabe`...

So you should probably only include the `CommandText` (or create a new DTO object and seralize that if you need multiple properties) with:

```
[Serializable]
public class CommandObjectSource : VisualizerObjectSource
{
    public override void GetData(object target, Stream outgoingData)
    {
        if (target != null && target is DbCommand)
        {
            DbCommand command = (DbCommand)target;

            var writer = new StreamWriter(outgoingData);
            writer.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

And read it with:

```
public class TestVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
{
    protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
    {
        string command;
        try
        {
            command = new StreamReader(objectProvider.GetData()).ReadLine();
            MessageBox.Show(command);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill try this when i get to work if it works ill be so happy :)